# RegEx Negative Lookahead with Repeating String

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a source string that has the same string repeating multiple times.  I need to match between the last occurrence of the string (String A) and another string (String B).  There are multiple occurrences of String A before String B.

I have been unable to find a Negative Lookahead to will work.

## Skip Down to Revised Source String

#### Source String

`<a href="Link1">some text 1</a><a href="Link2">some text 2</a><a href="Link3">Required text</a><a href="Link4">some text 4</a>`

NOTE:  The number of String A (`<a href=`) occurrences can vary.

#### Required Results

Match: `<a href="Link3">Required text</a>`
with Capture Group 1:
`Link 3`

Using this RegEx pattern:
`<a href="(.+?)".+?>Required text<\/a>`

It matches:
`<a href="Link1">some text 1</a><a href="Link2">some text 2</a><a href="Link3">Required text</a>`
Capture Group1: `Link 1`

You can view the setup here:  https://regex101.com/r/XsEmXw/1/

I have tried many different Negative Lookaheads, and none have worked.  For example:
`<a href="(.+?)"(?!.+?\<a href.+?Required).+?>Required text<\/a>`

TIA for your help.

---

### Revised Source String

OK, my bad, I over-simplified the Source String in the above description.

 The actual Source String is very complicated.  You can view it here:
https://regex101.com/r/VHrrNj/1/

The answer provided below is very clever, but unfortunately does not work for the full complex case:
`<a href="([^"]*)".+?Read more.+?<\/a>`

#### Revised Required Result

Match:
`<a href="https://s2.washingtonpost.com/298378e/5ece9636e6e81b69fea16209/597ba5e59bbc0f6826cfe531/2/10/1db89a19afda3018ce8cfede0cfb6768" style="color: #2a2a2a; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Read more »</a>`

Capture Group 1:  `https://s2.washingtonpost.com/298378e/5ece9636e6e81b69fea16209/597ba5e59bbc0f6826cfe531/2/10/1db89a19afda3018ce8cfede0cfb6768`

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Why are you not using [**parser**](https://www.w3.org/Library/src/HTML.html) for this requirement.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about the "parser".  How would I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a negative lookahead here. You can solve this by using this regex:

```
<a href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>Read more[^<]*<\/a>
```

Comment: Paul, thank you very much for your quick reply and excellent answer.  Unfortunately it does not work for my full, real-world, Source String.  Please see my revision to my Question above.

Comment: Does this work: `<a href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>Read more[^<]*<\/a>`

Comment: Yes!!!  Many thanks.  Please change your above answer (or add another) and I'll pick it as the solution.  You are clearly a RegEx genius.  I will have to study your solution to understand it so I can apply your technique in the future.

Comment: Here's the updated RegEx101 with Paul's revised answer:  https://regex101.com/r/VHrrNj/2/